# Can't log in to my Facebook App on local machine through ruby on rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Ruby on Rails site, and am in the process of redoing the Facebook app.

The trouble is that when I try to login via Facebook on my local machine, the web server crashes and I get an error of 'Abort Trap 6.'

More of that error message:

```
/Users/**/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:303:     
[BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin12.4.0]
Abort trap: 6
```

Now, after I get 'Abort Trap 6,' I can start up the web server again, but if I go to my localhost:port configuration, I wind up at an error page that looks like this:

```
undefined method `call' for 1025:Fixnum
```

And then it won't work — nothing at all works.

I know the Facebook App ID/Secret is correct, so can anyone point me in the right direction? (I know I'm on an older version of ruby/rails, but I unfortunately can't update).

Comment: I guess this the specific ruby 1.8 version error, or may be event not in ruby, but in rake/active_package link. Please make sure that you have used only release versions of all gems.

Comment: Looks like I didn't have an updated table in my database. All fixed now. Thanks for the help!